# AWS Glue as Hive Datasource

Tags: hive, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I've read AWS Glue is a a Hive compatible datastore, but I haven't found how to use AWS Glue as a JDBC datasource.

I'd like to use AWS Glue Catalog as a source for my reporting, as the Hive documentation shows here -
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-ConnectionURLforRemoteorEmbeddedMode

```
Connection URL for Remote or Embedded Mode
The JDBC connection URL format has the prefix jdbc:hive2:// and the Driver class is org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver. Note that this is different from the old HiveServer.

For a remote server, the URL format is jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>;initFile=<file> (default port for HiveServer2 is 10000).
For an embedded server, the URL format is jdbc:hive2:///;initFile=<file> (no host or port).
```

When I edit the database in AWS Glue, it appears I can set a location for client - but I'm not sure what to put here, and didn't see any documentation on how this works.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Athena via JDBC ? You can access Glue catalog via Athena

Answer (score 1):

AWS Glue is a Hive Metadata Store, not a Hive server.

Though, Hive server can use Glue as the metadata store.
https://aws.amazon.com/emr/features/hive/